# Как правильно поступать с неполными и не развернутыми ответами в очереди проверок?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, удаление-ответов

Есть [такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019549/212981) на вопрос из [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/394656):

> [image: Очередь проверок]

Видно, что ответ неполный и не развернутый. В комментариях уже указали на эти недостатки. В "*Рекомендовать удаление*" нет подходящего пункта. "*Выглядит нормально*" не поставить. "*Править*" тоже не вариант для моего случая. Остаётся только "*Пропустить*", но, мне кажется, что это не совсем правильно (система считает, что я прошёл мимо, хотя это не так).

Как лучше поступать с подобными ответами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалять следует только действительно бесполезные "ответы" (голые ссылки, спам, новые вопросы и т.п.). Т.е. если ответ хоть чуть-чуть полезен, но неполон и общ - оставьте его - он лучше, чем ничего. А если есть время и силы дополните или напишите рядом свой.

Также можно поставить флаг для модератора, чтобы он преобразовал ответ в комментарий.

Comment: Как именно можно поставить флаг для модератора?

Comment: Открываете ответ в новой вкладке, жмете "тревогу" и выбираете "требуется вмешательство модератора", а в очереди жмете "Пропустить".

Comment: «удалено ЮрийСПб♦ 21 час назад» ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal у вас меньше 10к. Мне показывает "преобразовано в комментарий ЮрийСПб♦ 21 час назад". И комментарий действительно присутствует ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Хм, а в [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/394656) мне «удалено» пишет. [дефект]?)

Comment: @andreymal в очереди точно так же - "преобразовано .."

Comment: Значит видимо у меня рейтинга не хватает, чтобы правду видеть)

Answer (score 4):

При голосовании за удаление вы не указываете причину, а оставляете стандартный комментарий. Если нужный комментарий под сообщением уже есть - совершенно не обязательно оставлять ещё один, можно выбрать пункт *"Комментарий не требуется"*.

Если же нужного комментария нет - вы можете оставить комментарий самостоятельно и в свободной форме, а потом всё так же выбрать пункт *"Комментарий не требуется"*.